# Netgear a7000 usb wifi is not seen in 18.04

Tags: drivers

I am a noobe to ubuntu I downloaded Desktop 18.04. I have the netgear a7000 usb wifi that is not being recognized by 18.04.  I have searched the internet for help and have found none.  The a7000 seems to be using the RTL8814A chipset.  Need help on how to get the drivers and then how to install them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: create an account at GitHub. 
use the following:

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install git dkms
- git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au.git (will ask for username and password.
- sudo dkms add ./rtl8814au
- sudo dkms build -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21
- sudo dkms install -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21